# Diagnostics Tool for embedded device

Tags: embedded-linux

I have an embedded system running Linux, with many peripheral devices connected.
There are some storage devices connected too. Currently, we do not have any diagnostics tool to check the state of devices on the system. 
what I want to do with this diagnostics tool is something like:
After connecting to my embedded system either via USB or network port, I want to be able to browse storage media ( in read only mod ), and may be later in future extend this to check the status of other devices running.
With this question, I am seeking guidance of expert people who have faced similar problem and were successfully implement a solution. 
I am not looking for a solution but a likely approach.

thanks

Comment: What exactly you want ? Check that content of files on storage devices not damaged? Number of file system errors? Number of bad blocks on your nand storage device?

Comment: I want to be able to access my storage media(SRAM,USB scratch, SATA) via this diagnostics tool and browse the contents

Comment: If you use embedded linux then there is huge possibility that you have `dropbear` on it, just start it, and then use `sshfs` on your PC to access its(device) `fs` Why you need some diagnostic tool for that

Answer (score 0):

one approach is that (it totally depends on your embedded board)

if your board supports booting from the usb, you can modify your bootloader code to boot linux initrd image from the usb, if usb is plugged in your board, otherwise noraml booting procedure.

you can write one c diagnostic utility to check the status of different peripherals and generate the report on the usbdisk

create Linux initrd image for your board with modified rcS file to mount the usb in Linux and start the utility while boot up, copy the utility in bin folder of your rootfilesystem.

now when you power-on your board with usb connected, your testing software will boot and test the peripherals otherwise your normal software will boot.

hope this helps!!